# Setting the name of a file saved through a filefield

Tags: silverstripe

I have a form that allows users to upload a resume through a form.

The submit method saves the data into CareerApplication with the resume attached as a has_one relation.

```
$submission = new CareerApplication();
$form->saveInto($submission);
```

I would like to control the filename the resume is saved as.

How can i set the filename of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this

```
$up = new Upload();

$file = Object::create('File');

$file->setFileName('newname');

$up->loadIntoFile($data['FileName'], $file, 'Uploads/Files');

if($up->isError()) {
    //handle error here
    //var_dump($up->getErrors());
}else {
      //file uploaded
      $file->ID;            
}
```