# SilverStripe UploadField file auto renaming

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe

I have made a form on the front end to upload some images. My idea is to automatically rename all files uploaded into unique id's.

I have looked at the SilverStripe API and I do not see anything about that. [UploadField API](https://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-UploadField.html)

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked this answer on the SilverStripe forum? https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/20232

Comment: No i didn't view this. Thanks! If I extend UploadField as MyUpload, must I include all the upload function with the modification into MyUpload extended class? Is it the right way to do this? it's a long function...

Comment: Yeah, I think you would have to, because the code that you want to alter is in the middle of the function. Something to keep in mind here is the code used in that answer would be old 3.1 or 3.0 upload function code. If you wanted to do this you would want to copy the latest version of that function and add the file renaming into it. One suggestion, rather than `MyUpload` call is something like `RandomNameUploadField`.

Comment: This StackOverflow answer might also be worth looking into: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930368/setting-the-name-of-a-file-saved-through-a-filefield

Comment: Stéphane, does that code work for you? If so post that as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Not exactly... I have include the upload function. But it are very different from the link you show me. I use Silverstripe 3.5.3. I don't know where to put the 2 lines of codes in the function like he do in the forum.

Comment: @3dgoo I have put new codes in my question. This code are from framework/form/uploadfield.php. Is it the right file to get upload function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution bellow, in Silverstripe 3.X we must extend UploadField with another class. Then copy the ''saveTemporaryFile'' function into it.

Just before ''try'', just have to add :

```
$ext = array_reverse(explode('.',$tmpFile['name'])); // explode filename into array, reverse array, first array key will then be file extension
$tmpFile['name'] = hash_hmac('sha256', $tmpFile['name'], '12345') . '.' . $ext[0];
```

---

Results :

```
class RandomNameUploadField extends UploadField {


protected function saveTemporaryFile($tmpFile, &$error = null) {

    // Determine container object
    $error = null;
    $fileObject = null;

    if (empty($tmpFile)) {
        $error = _t('UploadField.FIELDNOTSET', 'File information not found');
        return null;
    }

    if($tmpFile['error']) {
        $error = $tmpFile['error'];
        return null;
    }

    // Search for relations that can hold the uploaded files, but don't fallback
    // to default if there is no automatic relation
    if ($relationClass = $this->getRelationAutosetClass(null)) {
        // Create new object explicitly. Otherwise rely on Upload::load to choose the class.
        $fileObject = Object::create($relationClass);
    }

    $ext = array_reverse(explode('.',$tmpFile['name'])); // explode filename into array, reverse array, first array key will then be file extension
    $tmpFile['name'] = hash_hmac('sha256', $tmpFile['name'], '12345') . '.' . $ext[0];

    // Get the uploaded file into a new file object.
    try {
        $this->upload->loadIntoFile($tmpFile, $fileObject, $this->getFolderName());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // we shouldn't get an error here, but just in case
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        return null;
    }

    // Check if upload field has an error
    if ($this->upload->isError()) {
        $error = implode(' ' . PHP_EOL, $this->upload->getErrors());
        return null;
    }

    // return file
    return $this->upload->getFile();
}



}
```

Thanks [@3dgoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715759/3dgoo) to give me a part of the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I don't now about a API but with some code I was able to do that.

You have two possibilities.

First using database.

Second using only code:

```
$directory = '/teste/www/fotos/';
$files = glob($directory . '*.jpg');

if ( $files !== false )
{
    $filecount = count( $files );
    $newid = $filecount+1;
    $new_name = "foto_".$newid;
    $target_file =  $directory."/".$new_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

}
else
{
     $new_name = "foto_1";
     $target_file =  $directory."/".$new_name;
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
```

My example is for jpeg but you can look for hall types.

Comment: This does not automatically rename the files on upload when using the `SilverStripe` `UploadField`.

Comment: If you want some help you have to put some of your code so that I and other people can help.

Comment: Sorry I haven't noticed that I didn't put the code for uploaded the file.